# How can i get the values from this array?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array

In `$attval` when use `foreach` loop to print out the elements I get this output:

```
Array( 
      [0]
         (
          [id]=>1,
          [name]=>xxx
         )
      [0]
         (
          [id]=>2,
          [name]=>abc
         )
)
```

For some reason both indices are the same.
I think I can still get the values using the multidimensional array, but i am confused as to how I can?

Comment: What code are you using to output this?

Comment: @Pekka,  foreach ($attval as $kk=>$val){ print_r($attval[$kk]);  }

Comment: But what code are you using to output the structure you show above?

Comment: He says in his code print_r. What exactly is $attval, can you post us some code in your question please. Notable, what does $attval contain and what is the loop you execute on it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is something like this:

```
$attval = array();
$attval[0] = array("id"=>1,"name"=>"xxx");
$attval[1] = array("id"=>2,"name"=>"abc");
```

You can access individual properties like this:

```
$attval[0]['id']; // 1
$attval[1]['name']; // abc
```

You are showing a print_r of each sub-array, therefore your output should be:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => xxx
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => abc
)
```

If you want a full view of the array you could just do:

```
print_r($attval);
```

Then you get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => xxx
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => abc
        )

)
```